# when running get() using queryBuidler, Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

I am trying to run this SQL query:

```
SELECT head_account_id, account_id, created_on, result, COUNT(*) AS counter FROM notes
WHERE result = 'not_processed' AND created_on >= (now() - INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND created_on <= (now() - INTERVAL 8 HOUR)
AND account_id IN (SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE account_status = 'approved' AND demo = 0)
GROUP BY account_id
ORDER BY head_account_id, account_id, created_on DESC;
```

using Laravel querybuilder:

```
$appointments = DB::table('confirmed_appointments')
            ->select('head_account_id','account_id','created_on','result', DB::raw('count(*) as counter'))
            ->where('result', 'not_processed')
            ->where('created_on', '>=', DB::raw('now() - interval 3 day'))
            ->where('created_on', '<=', DB::raw('now() - interval 8 hour'))
            ->whereIn('account_id', $id)
            ->groupBy('account_id')
            ->orderBy('head_account_id')
            ->orderBy('account_id')
            ->orderBy('created_on', 'desc')
            ->get();
```

where $id is:

```
$id   = DB::table('accounts')
            ->select('id')
            ->where('account_status','Approved')
            ->where('demo','0')
            ->get();
```

And this above query works properly - I've checked using dd().

I am running into an error at $appointments= ..... -> get():

> "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

I understand that get() usually returns a stdClass object, but I don't understand why I can't use get() at all. A lot of the other solutions say to use get() -> toArray();  however I can't even get get() to run properly.. If I don't run get() and run dd() on the results, I get an array of information about the query but not the results itself.

I am new to Laravel/PHP so I might be lacking in knowledge but I hope that somebody can help me.

thanks for your time!

Comment: And `dd($id)` shows __what exactly__?

Comment: after what you do with the result? do you echo the result in the view?

Comment: @SalarBahador - I try to dd() it but I can't get there as I can't perform the get() function. But after that I would loop through the results.

Comment: @u_mulder The result looks like this:
Collection {#722 ▼
  #items: array:12 [▼
    0 => {#724 ▼
      +"id": 2
    }
    1 => {#717 ▼
      +"id": 3
    }
    2 => {#720 ▼
      +"id": 4
    }
    3 => {#725 ▶}
    4 => {#721 ▶}
    5 => {#727 ▶}
    6 => {#728 ▶}
    7 => {#729 ▶}
    8 => {#730 ▶}
    9 => {#731 ▶}
    10 => {#732 ▶}
    11 => {#733 ▶}
  ]
}

Comment: There's already a `pluck` solution in an answer.

Comment: It has no bussines with get. you get the result in the collection object. just foreach the result and access id like this : foreach($results as $result) echo $result->id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to retrieve an array of id values with `pluck()`, i.e.:

```
$id = DB::table('accounts')
        ->select('id')
        ->where('account_status','Approved')
        ->where('demo','0')
        ->pluck('id');
```

With `get()` you are retrieving, in the $id var, a collection of standard objects.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  This worked perfectly. I never would have expected the problem to be outside of the actual select stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about the get method that you run into that error. It's about what tou trying to do with result of that query. if you tring to echo the result of collection class it throws that error. you can not echo an object right?

According to documentation:

**get()** returns a collection object. it means it has array of results in it. in your case it return collection object that contains any record ids that mathes the query

**first()** return just one result contains one record

if you want only one id to return and can treated as string , so that you could echo it in your view you must use first() method instead.

coclusion:

If you want may ids use get(), and must foraech loop for every single result.
If you want may just one id use first();

But be aware even if you use first it returns std class, so in this case if you want to access id. you must write `$result->id` and echo it out.

Answer (score 0):

In your case `$id` is a full row of your matched data and you need only the id column so you need to do this

```
$id   = DB::table('accounts')
            ->select('id')
            ->where('account_status','Approved')
            ->where('demo','0')
            ->get();
//The ID column
$id = $id->id;
```